# Animation scheduledTimer error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

keep saying error of the method endBlink is not found in the code. can any one help me to fix it ??? i think is the selector parameter issue with the new  syntax style for swift 3

```
private func endBlink(timer : Timer){

    // some action to do
}

private func startBlink(){

        faceView.eyeOpen = false
        // wait a section then open eyes 
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0,
                             target:  self,
                             selector:self.endBlink(_:),
                             userInfo: nil,
                             repeats: false)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "private" for the first method, and apply "#selector":

```
func endBlink(timer:Timer){
        // some action to do
}


private func startBlink(){
        faceView.eyeOpen = false
        // wait a section then open eyes
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0,
                             target:  self,
                             selector:#selector(endBlink),
                             userInfo: nil,
                             repeats: false)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@objc
func endBlink() {

}

private func startBlink(){

    faceView.eyeOpen = false
    // wait a section then open eyes 
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0,
                         target:  self,
                         selector:#selector(endBlink),
                         userInfo: nil,
                         repeats: false)

}
```